# iPhone UIWebView PDF Page Jump

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pdf, uikit, uiwebview

I want to view a local PDF (in my iPhone app) and be able to jump to a specific page.  Seems like the UIWebView is the way to go, however, I can't find any information on jumping to specific pages.  Is this impossible?  Are there any other techniques I can use?

thanks,
Howie

Comment: Refer [display specific pdf page in the UIWebview ios](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28601694/1106035)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using Javascript. See [this link](http://shortdivision.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/going-back-to-the-last-place-you-were-in-a-uiwebview/) for more details. You'll want to use something along the lines of `@"window.scrollTo(0, x);"`, where x is some value you determined by playing around with the WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to set the content offset of the UIWebView like Mike pointed out (but without involving JavaScript):

```
webView.ScrollView.SetContentOffset(new PointF(0, y), true);
```

(sorry for the MonoTouch code but ObjectiveC is still on my todo list)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to an UIWebView, you can use the Quartz API :http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

It's more complicated, but you should be able to do whatever you want.