# How to show a PDF page by page using horizontal swipe in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, viewer, horizontal-scrolling

I would like to add to my app a pdf viewer which can scroll horizontally. Anyone know how to do it? I'm making several attempts but without success. Thanks. Matteo

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebViewController in landscape orientation and this piece of code can give you an idea about how to display pdfs:

```
 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 480 )];
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"pdf"];
 NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
 [webView loadRequest:request];
 webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
 [self.view addSubview:webView];
 [webView release];
```

Comment: thanks but what I need is horizontal scrolling (ie. change page swiping from left to right or right to left). Uiwebview doesn't support such scroll

Comment: Then you may try UIGestureRecognizer and swipe gesture and then change the page accordingly. There is also a page curling effect if you need to.

Comment: but I need to use other components than uiwebview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974304/iphone-uiwebview-pdf-page-jump