# How to jump pdf page in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uiwebview

I'm trying to scroll the pdf file by page

here is my code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPdffile" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webview loadRequest:urlrequest];

webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;

[super viewDidLoad];

}

//goto next page

-(IBAction)nextpage{

        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: ?????? ];
}

//goto previous page

-(IBAction)prevpage {

       ?????
}
```

what should i put after `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`?

do i put same code in "prevpage"?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone UIWebView PDF Page Jump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974304/iphone-uiwebview-pdf-page-jump)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 5 you can use this statement for page jumping

```
[[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,y) animated:YES];
```

and in below iOS 5 you can use this statement

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, %f)", y]];
```

Where y is the height where you're going to jump.

Here i am writing some sample code for next and previous page

```
-(IBAction) nextPage: (id) sender
{
    if (currentPage < numberOfPages) 
    {
        float y =  pageHeight * currentPage++;

        if (isIOSAbove4) 
        {
            [[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,y) animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, %f)", y]];
        }
    }
}
```

For previous page:

```
-(IBAction) prevPage: (id) sender
{   
    if (currentPage - 1)
    {
        float y = --currentPage * pageHeight - pageHeight;
        if (isIOSAbove4) 
        {
            [[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,y) animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, %f)", y]];
        }
    }
}
```

in above sample code isIOSAbove4 is defined in pch file

```
#define isIOSAbove4 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0)
```

Hope above code will solve your problem

Comment: I assume you have a constant for pageHeight. I have found that the pageHeight changes, even relative to a constant PDFRect and will cause page position calculations that get worse with longer documents. This solution also assumes pages inside a document are all the same orientation.

Comment: Note: this should be called after viewWillAppear. viewDidAppear will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a way to do this, in other web browsers/PDF viewers you could use the querystring parameter to ?page=6 but that doesnt appear to be supported by the WebKit PDF engine

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem myself! As the pages arent rendered as HTML performing JS queries on them dont work

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem, in which I had to navigate to particular page in PDF (which is displayed using UIWebView) on selection of a cell in tableView (thumbnail tableview).

So I wrote a piece of code which allows you to scroll to particular page in PDF. This works even if the PDF is in zoomed state. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/raghuveer553/NRPDFReader).